# Detect Customized Twitter Bootstrap Settings (CSS, Variables, & Plugins)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, customization

I have built a site using Twitter Bootstrap.

When I [customized my Bootstrap download](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html) I set custom values for colors, gutter widths, etc.

Two months later, I would like to upgrade to Bootstrap Version 2.3.0 but have forgotten what values I set for these custom values.

Rather than going through all of my code and searching for these values and plugging them into my new customized download package, is there a way to "Import" my current bootstrap.css file, detect the settings, and then upgrade to the new version?

I have seen functionality such as this on the [jQuery Mobile Themeroller](http://jquerymobile.com/themeroller/index.php) whereby you import your CSS by copy & paste, and the site performs the upgrade for you.

Is there anything similar for Twitter Bootstrap? Or is there a way to do this without comparing hundreds of lines of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git clone` the repository. Then `git checkout <your original version>`, then copy your changes over top and do a diff. This will allow you to see only the changes you made to the version you originally used without seeing all the changes in the new bootstrap version. You can then update to the HEAD and proceed to copy your changes into it.

Comment: I need to filter out a couple customizations so that they fallback to the defaults while keeping the custom gutters, etc. If your answer works, could you please provide a little more detail?

Comment: I'm not really familiar with `git` (I've downloaded files, commented, etc. but never used a repository or anything). So in essence, your answer is saying take my code, and then get a "clean" version from the downloader, and utilize some sort of "code compare" tool to view the differences? If yes, then is there another tool that you know of if I'm not using a repository?

Comment: You could use something like kdiff3 to compare the files. Any diff tool should do.

Comment: If you are not already familiar with git, Notepad++ and a few other text editors come with more intuitive compare tools. There are even online tools for that: http://www.mergely.com/

Comment: What I'm actually trying to do is remove tinynav.js and it's CSS from my bootstrap site, and utilize the default nav collapse found in Twitter Bootstrap. Help?